# Interactively customize theme-tied faces

Tags: faces, themes, customize-face

`M-x customize-face` is great and `custom-theme-set-faces` is a great function. Can I have these two tied together easily so that I can interactively customize a face that will be tied to the currently chosen theme? We can assume there's only one theme enabled.

Comment: Yes, it seems like some feature is missing. (Or maybe I'm missing something.) If you don't get a good answer here, consider filing an enhancement request. You do that using `M-x report-emacs-bug`.